# Mobile browsers and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xhtml, mobile, browser

Can't every mobile browsers support JavaScript? Which language/technology are used in mobile browsers pages? I mean the mobile websites...

I know XHTML is used much, What are the rest?

Comment: XHTML is not used at all - well, almost not at all. It may be used for the markup, and maybe even the DOCTYPE, but that is irrelevant since the vast bulk is served as text/html.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone and default Android and BlackBerry all use WebKit. Opera and FireFox offer mobile browsers as options.

Windows Phone uses a version of IE9.

All of above support JavaScript. You can see phones from 2+ years ago that have browsers w/o JS, but they're not common anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern smartphones' browsers are based on Webkit - the same engine that powers Chrome and Safari. IE on Windows Phone 7 and Firefox are supposed to be standards-compliant too. Opera does have some support but don't count on it too much.

So, yes, they do support Javascript, and the technology stack is the same as for desktop ones (HTML, CSS, javascript). You even get broader support for HTML5/CSS3 in them.

Older phones, however, are a completely different story, and believe me, you don't want to go there :)

Comment: `Modern smartphones' browsers are based on Webkit`? Opera, Microsoft, NetFront, Mozilla and many others might have something to say about that.

Comment: BlackBerry/webOS/Nokia latest phones all use webkit. Sorry, but NetFront doesn't qualify as "modern". I did forget about Opera/FF though, edited :)